# Installing MySql service with --defaults-file option does not install service

Tags: database, mysql

I am trying to install a service using an explicit defaults file as described here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-config-wizard-file-location.html

The command I am running is:

```
mysqld --install "AwesomeMysqlService" --defaults-file="C:\my.ini"
```

If I run this I get a warning and the service is not installed:

```
2014-04-04 12:01:17 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. enter code here`Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
```

I have tried adding:
`--explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=1` and that gets rid of the warning, however the service is still not installed.

No further output is produced even when running with `--debug`

If I just install the service without the defaults file I get back:

`Service successfully installed.`

I dont understand why this is not working. I have recently upgraded MySQL to 5.6. so I wonder if this has something to do with it.

I am probably doing something silly :P

Thanks

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that mysqld only allows you to specify one argument if you use a service name.

e.g. if you just use the default instance name (MySql) you can add as many arguments as you want.

`mysqld --install --port=3100 --datadir="C:\Data"` etc

However if you give your instance a name, you can only specify 1 additional argument:

`mysqld --install fooSql --defaults-file=my.ini`